# How to zip multiple files in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to zip multiple files using a button in ASP.Net MVC3

Your answers will be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Use a C# zip library, like [this one.](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)  Alternatively, you can [try this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/209731/Csharp-use-Zip-archives-without-external-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [dotnetzip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) (Open source)

Simple code:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
  zip.AddFile("Resume.doc");
  zip.AddFile("Portrait.png");
  zip.Save("Package.zip");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! this thing really zip files but how can i specify the location of the files i want to zip and a popup saying the details of the zip files and if i want to open or save,stuffs like that.