# Zip and Unzip multiple files in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, zip

I need to zip a set of files with extension .xml from a particular folder. I am workin in WPF  c#. I have searched several forums. Default utility Gzip may not serve my purpose. How can i do it??

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243929/how-to-zip-multiple-files-using-only-net-api-in-c-sharp

Comment: have you googled? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852541/how-to-zip-multiple-files-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: there are plenty of libraries for C#, pick one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Sharp Zip Lib.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Answer (score 1):

Try an open source project at *codeplex* :

- [DotNetZip - Zip and Unzip in C#, VB, any .NET language](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)